# Filter Backgrid columns by number

Tags: backbone.js, backgrid

With a table like this

```
1|2|3
4|1|1
1|1|1
```

Now I want to filter by columns with numbers >=3, I would get:

```
1|2|3
4|1|1
```

The ClientFilter library seems to only be made for strings (regex implementation).  Is there an alternate way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Backgrid classes are easily extensible, so all you need to do is create your own filter class which overrides  `ClientSideFilter.makeMatcher` function like so:

```
var GreaterThanClientFilter = Backgrid.Extension.ClientSideFilter.extend({  
  makeMatcher: function(query){
      var q = 1*query;
      return function (model) {
          if (isNaN(q)) return false;
          var keys = this.fields || model.keys();
          for (var i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) {
              value = model.get(keys[i]);
              if (!isNaN(value) &&  (1*value >= q))
                  return true;
            }
          return false;
      };
  }  
});

var filter = new GreaterThanClientFilter({
  collection: collection
});
```

Running example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yishaib/m295H/)